# Find such type of headings and then place a new word above that div

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD></HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff">


  <DIV>
    <H3 CLASS="Heading-1">First Level Heading</H3> 
    <DIV>
      <H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
        <P CLASS="Tab-Text-7">Some Text Here</P>
      </DIV>


      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
              Some Cotents Here
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </DIV>

      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" class="green1">
              Some text goes here
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </DIV>


      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third level Heading</H6>
      </DIV>
      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-4">Fourth Level Heading </H6>
        Some Text Goes here
      </DIV>


      <DIV>
        <H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
        <DIV>
          <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading   </H6>
          <TABLE>
            <TR>
              <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" class="blue1">
                SOme text goes here
              </TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </DIV>
      </DIV> <DIV>
      <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
      Some text goes here
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Expected Output:-

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff">

xxxxx

<DIV>
<H3 CLASS="Heading-1">First Level Heading</H3>  
<DIV>
<H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
<P CLASS="Tab-Text-7">Some Text Here</P>
</DIV>

xxxxx

<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
Some Cotents Here
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>

xxxxx

<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1"class="green1">   
Some text goes here
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>

xxxxx

<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third level Heading</H6>
</DIV>
<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-4">Fourth Level Heading </H6>
Some Text Goes here
</DIV>

xxxxx

<DIV>
<H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading   </H6>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" class="blue1">
SOme text goes here
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>

xxxxx

<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
Some text goes here
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

From Above code i want to search the Headings and place "XXXXX" above that headings .If it contains any child heading(i.e Heading 1 contains Heading 2),then at that time it should place the "XXXXX" word above parent heading instead of child heading.(heading 1 is parent )

Can any one Help me please.

Comment: Could you please try to clarify a little further what you want to achieve? Getting the expected output would be an acceptable answer?

Comment: Sure Buddy. Thanks for your reply.

you can see the code from that, i want to search the class whose name is heading-1 or Heading-2 etc. and from that i want to place or add new word or string above that div.

also if it contains subchild (i.e heading 1 contains heaing 2 and heading 3 ) childs.so at that time it should place the new word before Heading-1 <div>, instead of heading-3 or Heading-2,<div>

In expected output, i have showed clearly what i need in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**THIS**](https://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/rebpb5h2/5/) is what you want.

1) JQuery checks for every heading on the document.
2) Then searchs if the parent has another heading before.
3) If there are no headings before parent it adds the content before that heading.

```js
$(document).find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().prev().is('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6') != true) {
        $(this).parent().before('<p>xxxxxxx</p>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV>
<H3 CLASS="Heading-1">First Level Heading</H3>  
<DIV>
<H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
<P CLASS="Tab-Text-7">Some Text Here</P>
</DIV>


<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
Some Cotents Here
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>


<div>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1"class="green1">   
Some text goes here
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>


<div>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third level Heading</H6>
<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-4">Fourth Level Heading </H6>
Some Text Goes here
</DIV></DIV>


<DIV>
<H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading   </H6>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" class="blue1">
SOme text goes here
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>


<DIV>
<H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
Some text goes here
</DIV>
```

Comment: Hey @Aramil you didnt got my question.

instead of placing xxxxx to first level,you have placed xxxxx after each levels.

Comment: I pasted an older version of the code, check it now. If this isn't what you wanted then I missunderstood

Comment: Thanks @Aramil Rey It works.

You Have done a great job Buddy, Really Appreciative work done by you.


Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <DIV class="Find-Me">
    <H3 CLASS="Heading-1">First Level Heading</H3>  
    <DIV>
      <H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
   <DIV>
   <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
   <P CLASS="Tab-Text-7">Some Text Here</P>
  </DIV>

  <DIV class="Find-Me">
   <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
   <TABLE>
     <TR>
      <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
       Some Cotents Here
      </TD>
     </TR>
   </TABLE>
</DIV>
  <script>
    function Insert() {
      $('<p>xxxx</p>').insertBefore('.Find-Me');
    }
    Insert();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Here in Div you have assigned new class name.

without assigning that i need to find and place new word.

please can you help me,without asssignig that class to div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body > div').has([class^='Heading-']).prepend('XXXXXX');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but can you explain it in fiddle

Comment: You haven't set up a fiddle. Also, your HTML structure is faulty. you have more opening `<DIV>` tags than you close `</DIV>`.

Comment: its not working can you please show me how to use it